# How to make a a date sequence vector from given date to given another date? [R]

Tags: r, date

Im trying to compute a sequence of dates such to have at the output

```
2014-07-16
2014-07-18
2014-07-19
2014-07-20
```

when I'll have at the input

```
2014-07-16
2014-07-20
```

Any ideas?

It'll be perfect if this works but it does not :/

```
seq(from="2014-07-16", to="2014-07-20", by="day")
```

Thanks for help in advance !

Comment: Check out `?seq.Date`

Comment: Thanks for reply. Check @Gregor comment :) below

Comment: Sorry :/ should I delete my question now ?

Comment: You can't, as @Gregor got upvoted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R doesn't know that "2014-07-16" is a date unless you tell it so.

```
seq(from=as.Date("2014-07-16"), to=as.Date("2014-07-20"), by="day")
```